# VLC 2.1 compile for windows 32 bit on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, qt4, vlc

I am compiling VLC for 32-bit Windows using Ubuntu 14.04LTS and source code for version 2.1.0
I am at the last step i.e "build" of the procedure.

configure gives the following result:
libvlc configuration

version               : 2.1.0
system                : mingw32
architecture          : i686 mmx sse sse2
optimizations         : yes
vlc aliases           : cvlc rvlc qvlc svlc

than when I type in the "make" command,it gives the following output:

```
#define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      libqt4_plugin_la-main_interface.moc.lo
In file included from qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from main_interface.hpp:28,
                 from main_interface.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      libqt4_plugin_la-menus.moc.lo
In file included from qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from menus.hpp:28,
                 from menus.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      libqt4_plugin_la-dialogs_provider.moc.lo
In file included from dialogs_provider.hpp:29:0,
                 from dialogs_provider.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      libqt4_plugin_la-input_manager.moc.lo
In file included from input_manager.hpp:29:0,
                 from input_manager.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      libqt4_plugin_la-actions_manager.moc.lo
In file included from actions_manager.hpp:28:0,
                 from actions_manager.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      libqt4_plugin_la-extensions_manager.moc.lo
In file included from extensions_manager.hpp:28:0,
                 from extensions_manager.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      libqt4_plugin_la-recents.moc.lo
In file included from qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from recents.hpp:27,
                 from recents.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      adapters/libqt4_plugin_la-seekpoints.moc.lo
In file included from adapters/seekpoints.hpp:26:0,
                 from adapters/seekpoints.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      adapters/libqt4_plugin_la-chromaprint.moc.lo
In file included from adapters/chromaprint.hpp:24:0,
                 from adapters/chromaprint.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      adapters/libqt4_plugin_la-variables.moc.lo
In file included from adapters/variables.hpp:25:0,
                 from adapters/variables.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-playlist.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/playlist.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/playlist.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-bookmarks.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/bookmarks.hpp:28,
                 from dialogs/bookmarks.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-mediainfo.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/mediainfo.hpp:28,
                 from dialogs/mediainfo.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-extended.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/extended.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/extended.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-messages.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/messages.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/messages.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-epg.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/epg.hpp:26,
                 from dialogs/epg.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-errors.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/errors.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/errors.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-external.moc.lo
In file included from dialogs/external.hpp:25:0,
                 from dialogs/external.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-plugins.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/plugins.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/plugins.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-preferences.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/preferences.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/preferences.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-sout.moc.lo
In file included from dialogs/sout.hpp:28:0,
                 from dialogs/sout.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-convert.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/convert.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/convert.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-help.moc.lo
In file included from dialogs/help.hpp:28:0,
                 from dialogs/help.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-gototime.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/gototime.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/gototime.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-toolbar.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/toolbar.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/toolbar.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-open.moc.lo
In file included from dialogs/open.hpp:28:0,
                 from dialogs/open.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-openurl.moc.lo
In file included from dialogs/openurl.hpp:28:0,
                 from dialogs/openurl.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-podcast_configuration.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/qvlcframe.hpp:37,
                 from dialogs/podcast_configuration.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/podcast_configuration.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-vlm.moc.lo
In file included from dialogs/vlm.hpp:29:0,
                 from dialogs/vlm.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-firstrun.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from dialogs/firstrun.hpp:24,
                 from dialogs/firstrun.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-extensions.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from dialogs/extensions.hpp:27,
                 from dialogs/extensions.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-fingerprintdialog.moc.lo
In file included from dialogs/fingerprintdialog.hpp:24:0,
                 from dialogs/fingerprintdialog.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-extended_panels.moc.lo
In file included from components/extended_panels.hpp:29:0,
                 from components/extended_panels.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-info_panels.moc.lo
In file included from components/info_panels.hpp:30:0,
                 from components/info_panels.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-info_widgets.moc.lo
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-preferences_widgets.moc.lo
In file included from components/preferences_widgets.hpp:30:0,
                 from components/preferences_widgets.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-complete_preferences.moc.lo
In file included from components/complete_preferences.hpp:28:0,
                 from components/complete_preferences.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-simple_preferences.moc.lo
In file included from components/simple_preferences.hpp:28:0,
                 from components/simple_preferences.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-open_panels.moc.lo
In file included from components/open_panels.hpp:32:0,
                 from components/open_panels.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-interface_widgets.moc.lo
In file included from components/interface_widgets.hpp:30:0,
                 from components/interface_widgets.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-controller.moc.lo
In file included from components/controller.hpp:28:0,
                 from components/controller.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/libqt4_plugin_la-controller_widget.moc.lo
In file included from components/controller_widget.hpp:28:0,
                 from components/controller_widget.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/epg/libqt4_plugin_la-EPGChannels.moc.lo
  CXX      components/epg/libqt4_plugin_la-EPGRuler.moc.lo
  CXX      components/epg/libqt4_plugin_la-EPGView.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from components/epg/EPGItem.hpp:27,
                 from components/epg/EPGView.hpp:27,
                 from components/epg/EPGView.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/epg/libqt4_plugin_la-EPGWidget.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from components/epg/EPGItem.hpp:27,
                 from components/epg/EPGView.hpp:27,
                 from components/epg/EPGWidget.hpp:27,
                 from components/epg/EPGWidget.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/playlist/libqt4_plugin_la-views.moc.lo
In file included from ./util/../components/playlist/playlist_model.hpp:29:0,
                 from ./util/pictureflow.hpp:49,
                 from components/playlist/views.hpp:31,
                 from components/playlist/views.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/playlist/libqt4_plugin_la-vlc_model.moc.lo
In file included from components/playlist/vlc_model.hpp:28:0,
                 from components/playlist/vlc_model.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/playlist/libqt4_plugin_la-playlist_model.moc.lo
In file included from components/playlist/playlist_model.hpp:29:0,
                 from components/playlist/playlist_model.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/playlist/libqt4_plugin_la-playlist.moc.lo
In file included from components/playlist/playlist.hpp:30:0,
                 from components/playlist/playlist.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/playlist/libqt4_plugin_la-standardpanel.moc.lo
In file included from components/playlist/standardpanel.hpp:28:0,
                 from components/playlist/standardpanel.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/playlist/libqt4_plugin_la-selector.moc.lo
In file included from components/playlist/selector.hpp:29:0,
                 from components/playlist/selector.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/sout/libqt4_plugin_la-profile_selector.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from components/sout/profile_selector.hpp:27,
                 from components/sout/profile_selector.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      components/sout/libqt4_plugin_la-sout_widgets.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from components/sout/sout_widgets.hpp:27,
                 from components/sout/sout_widgets.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      util/libqt4_plugin_la-input_slider.moc.lo
In file included from util/input_slider.hpp:30:0,
                 from util/input_slider.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      util/libqt4_plugin_la-timetooltip.moc.lo
  CXX      util/libqt4_plugin_la-customwidgets.moc.lo
  CXX      util/libqt4_plugin_la-searchlineedit.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from util/searchlineedit.hpp:33,
                 from util/searchlineedit.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      util/libqt4_plugin_la-qmenuview.moc.lo
  CXX      util/libqt4_plugin_la-qvlcapp.moc.lo
In file included from ./qt4.hpp:29:0,
                 from util/qvlcapp.hpp:32,
                 from util/qvlcapp.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      util/libqt4_plugin_la-pictureflow.moc.lo
In file included from util/../components/playlist/playlist_model.hpp:29:0,
                 from util/pictureflow.hpp:49,
                 from util/pictureflow.moc.cpp:9:
../../../config.h:733:0: warning: "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  CXX      util/buttons/libqt4_plugin_la-RoundButton.moc.lo
  CXX      util/buttons/libqt4_plugin_la-DeckButtonsLayout.moc.lo
  CXX      util/buttons/libqt4_plugin_la-BrowseButton.moc.lo
  CXX      libqt4_plugin_la-resources.lo
  CXX      styles/libqt4_plugin_la-seekstyle.moc.lo
  CXX      dialogs/libqt4_plugin_la-ml_configuration.moc.lo
  CXX      components/playlist/libqt4_plugin_la-ml_model.moc.lo
  CXXLD    libqt4_plugin.la
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-menus.o:menus.cpp:(.rdata+0x1c0c): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-main_interface.o:main_interface.cpp:(.rdata+0x13e8): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-dialogs_provider.o:dialogs_provider.cpp:(.rdata+0x115c): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-actions_manager.o:actions_manager.cpp:(.rdata+0x2d4): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
dialogs/.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-preferences.o:preferences.cpp:(.rdata+0x6b8): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
dialogs/.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-extended.o:extended.cpp:(.rdata+0x388): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
dialogs/.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-toolbar.o:toolbar.cpp:(.rdata+0x14a8): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
components/.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-info_panels.o:info_panels.cpp:(.rdata+0xf4c): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
components/.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-simple_preferences.o:simple_preferences.cpp:(.rdata+0x3fa0): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
components/.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-interface_widgets.o:interface_widgets.cpp:(.rdata+0xe5c): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
components/.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-controller.o:controller.cpp:(.rdata+0x2948): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
components/playlist/.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-playlist.o:playlist.cpp:(.rdata+0xadc): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-main_interface_win32.o:main_interface_win32.cpp:(.rdata+0x2f4): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-main_interface.moc.o:main_interface.moc.cpp:(.rdata+0xa7c): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
components/.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-interface_widgets.moc.o:interface_widgets.moc.cpp:(.rdata+0xa84): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libuuid.a(lib32_libuuid_a-uuid.o):uuid.c:(.rdata$CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI[_CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI]+0x0): multiple definition of `CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI'
.libs/libqt4_plugin_la-qt4.o:qt4.cpp:(.rdata+0x108c): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[6]: *** [libqt4_plugin.la] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/shehryar/vlc/modules/gui/qt4'
make[5]: *** [all] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/shehryar/vlc/modules/gui/qt4'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/shehryar/vlc/modules/gui'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/shehryar/vlc/modules/gui'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/shehryar/vlc/modules'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shehryar/vlc'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the qt4-devel-tools and all the other prerequisites that are listed on the wiki page.